# Why can't I use a Partial Class in a VSTO Ribbon?

Tags: c#, vsto

I'm trying to break up a very big VSTO IRibbonExtensibility class into multiple smaller classes to make things more manageable.

I tried creating a partial class with all my Visibility callbacks in it.
The code compiles fine but doesn't work in MS Word.

Error: The call to GetCustomUI() for RibbonID 'Microsoft.Word.Document' failed.

Any idea why this isn't working??

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public partial class Ribbon : O.IRibbonExtensibility
{
..
}

public partial class Ribbon 
{
..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my bad..

I had moved the Ribbon.xml file into a new folder and that caused the issue